# How can I create a dot file that contains two schemas in the same database?(PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, svg, diagram, dot, neato

Basically I have two schemas on the same DB that I would like to put into a dot file using `postgresql_autodoc`. I have tied creating two separate .dot files and then packing them with gvpack.

However I run into an error telling that the first node in one of the files does not have a position.

I've also tried just combining the two graphs without packing and then running the command I found on stackoverflow (`ccomps -x graph.dot | dot | gvpack -array3 | neato -Tsvg -n2 -o graph.svg`), but it seems that the connections are not there.

Perhaps there is another program I could use that will create a master dot that contains the two schemas?

My ultimate goal here is to make it completely automated using a php and shell script combo that I can run after making changes and pull subsystems out of it using gvpr.

Let me know what you think guys! (64bit Ubuntu 12.04.2 - in case that's also needed)

Answer (score 0):

This may seem like a bit simple, because I haven't worked with the .dot files much but we use pg_autodoc to generate files with all schemas in a database.  We haven't had any problems.

So the first thing to do is just to run pg_autodoc on your database and generate a .dot file without selecting schemas.  This will give you all objects in all schemas.

If that fails to give you something you can use with your toolchain, then the next question is why, but that will have solved your immediate question.